# Xamarin + Unity IoC

Tags: c#, xamarin, unity-container

I am new to Xamarin Forms and am trying get [Microsoft Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647202.aspx) IoC framework integrated into it for use in an iOS/Android app.

Adding the Nuget package is simple enough but as soon as I add something that actually references Unity (e.g. `public static UnityContainer Container { get; private set; }`), my app dies at runtime with a

However, when I go to run it, my app dies immediately with a `FileNotFoundException` of `Microsoft.Practices.ServicesLocation`

Best I can tell my project is setup [similar to this tutorial project](http://arteksoftware.com/ioc-containers-with-xamarin/).

Comment: Which project did you add the nuget package to? You have to add it to the PCL, Android, and iOS.

Comment: I added it to every PCL and the `*.iOS` and `*.Droid` projects. Clean, rebuild, same result. Regardless shouldn't the references cascade down (like in Visual Studio)?

Comment: I have had issues were it doesn't build them in. Can you also check if https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommonServiceLocator/ is installed?

Comment: Unity has a soft reference to Common Service Locator which seems to be causing an issue.  If you manually install the CommonServiceLocator nuget package it should be OK.

Comment: Randy you were correct. Though I did have to add the reference to both the PCL and the `.iOS` app. If you write that up as an answer, I'll gladly accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity has a reference to Common Service Locator but the NuGet package does not have it as a dependency.  I believe this is by design (but I can't find it documented right now).

Usually this isn't an issue unless using UnityServiceLocator but it is causing an issue for you.  If you manually install the [CommonServiceLocator NuGet Package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/CommonServiceLocator/) it will resolve the issue.

Comment: Yes, this is by design.